# jQuery Mobile App + remote REST Webservice: Alternatives to JSONP?

Tags: http, rest, jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

Currently I'm working on a jQuery Mobile website which will later be transformed into an app via Titanium. I have created a RESTful JSON web service, which is running on a different server than the jQuery Mobile application. The web service is consumed via AJAX using JSONP.

One thing I find annoying is that I can't make use of HTTP error codes, because jQuery automatically aborts a JSONP call whenever the server issues an error. I can never get hold of the error code on the client side.

Another thing is that JSONP only works with the HTTP verb GET, you cannot issue a JSONP POST for example (Currently, the web service is GET only, but that could change).

Are there any alternatives to JSONP? Or is JSONP the only choice I have when using remote JSON web services with AJAX? For example, how do Twitter apps interact with the Twitter API (they have a REST API)?

Comment: I don't believe there are many alternatives to JSONP because of the limitations of the same origin policy. A Googling found [this post](http://donatstudios.com/JSONP) which has some info on why it exists. It sounds like the main issue is how jQuery makes the call for you; have you looked into writing/overriding the call to pass back the status code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Paul DelRe. Do you mean overwriting jQuery's ajax() function?

Comment: I would suggest you look at how to do it in javascript or how jQuery did it in javascript. I wouldn't change anything to your copy of the jQuery code because that makes it difficult to stay current when they release new version. Once you learn how they do it, you could write your own function, but I'm sure it's been done before, so Google first (like naugtur).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a nice illustration why people complain that jquery is too easy to adopt ;)

JSONP is not ajax. There are no success and failure callbacks. JSONP is this:

1. put the parameters in the url
2. add &jsoncallback=random2745273
3. create a global variable `random2745273` and put the callback reference in it
4. add `<script src="theurlhere"></script>` to the `head`
5. that's all you can do.

The server returns

```
random2745273({somedata});
```

and that's how your callback is called.

If you want to report errors, then your server has to generate a correct code. You will not know what HTTP headers were sent.

And this is the only way you can communicate cross-domain with an api.
Sending cross-domain communicates is also possible with generating iframes, but it's hacky and rarely used.

[edit]

Ok, that got me thinking... I could use the iframe hack to wrap over the JSONP!

And as usual - I wasn't the first to have the idea (and I'm finally humble enough to google my ideas expecting it ;) )

Here it is: http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/sandbox-your-cross-domain-jsonp-to-improve-mashup-security/

awesome

[edit2]

awww, I forgot... There's another one.

```
window.postMessage
```

It already got implemented in some browsers. If you don't have to be compatible with most of the browsers, you can start using it now! :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. However, I don't understand this sentence "If you want to report errors, then your server has to generate a correct code. You will not know what HTTP headers were sent." In my case, the server is generating the correct code, but still I have no way of accessing it. Or is there a way to access the error code?

Comment: I repeat - NOOOO :P You won't see a trace of a result in javascript unless the output of the server is a call to a function that exists. So by saying `the correct code` I mean something like `random2745273({"error":true});` in the body of a correct HTTP 200 response

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. The workaround you recommended is what I had already implemented. Thanks for your time and dedication.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research on postMessage I found an alternative to JSONP: AJAX via Cross-domain messaging with EasyXDM.

See http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/cross-domain-ajax/